# Выделение текста при клике на TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Требуется при клике на `TextBox` выделять текст. 
Собственно box-ы содержат пояснение, что вводить. Удалять по-умолчанию его не нужно. Но выделить перед введением текста, чтобы ускорить ввод, стоит.

Что пробовал:

```
textBox_name.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox_name.SelectionLength = textBox_name.Text.Length;
```

и

```
textBox_name.SelectAll();
```

По какой-то причине не срабатывает. Чувствую где-то рядом, но видимо что-то не учитываю.

Comment: Посмотрите решение [тут: stackoverflow.com select all text on focus in wpf textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox) или [тут: intertech.com Select All Text in a WPF TextBox on Focus](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/how-to-select-all-text-in-a-wpf-textbox-on-focus/) Там просто одни события забивают другие и выделение пропадает.

Comment: Я находил эти тексты. Буду капать. Но если кто поконкретнее подскажет и на русском, буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если внимательно присмотреться к элементу TextBox, то можно заметить, что при первом клике на нем происходит следующее: элемент приобретает фокус и каретка курсора встает на месте клика пользователя.

Когда мы пытаемся по события фокуса просто выделить весь текст внутри:

```
...
text = new TextBox();
text.Text = "Sample text";
text.GotFocus += text_GotFocus;
...
...
private void text_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = sender as TextBox;
    if(text != null) text.SelectAll();
}
...
```

Происходит следующее. Наш текстовый элемент получает событие (Preview)MouseLeftButtonDown, которое вызывает фокус и только потом устанавливает каретку в нужное положение, тем самым снимая наше выделение от события фокуса. Эта та причина, по которой при получении элементом фокуса от клавиатуры, выделение срабатывает нормально, а при клике нет.

Одним из вариантов решения является самому отловить событие нажатия мыши и обработать его, но у элемента TextBox отсутствуют какие-либо события мышки кроме (preview)DoubleMouseClick. Для того, что бы решить эту проблему, используется регистрация события на все элементы TextBox через  `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler`. При этом событие останавливается и элементу передается событие фокуса.

```
...
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), 
                                  UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
                                  new MouseButtonEventHandler(StopTextBoxClick), 
                                  true);
...
...
private void StopTextBoxClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = sender as TextBox;

    if(text != null){
        e.Handled = true;
        text.Focus();
    }
}
...
```

В данном варианте остается одна проблема, теперь каждый раз срабатывает событие фокуса и текст остается выделенным всегда, а мышь не работает. Последней правкой является остановка событие только тогда, когда фокус у элемента еще не получен. Для этого можно использовать свойство IsFocused, но поскольку элемент может содержать еще какие-то вложенные элементы, используется `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`.

Кстати, событие получения фокуса можно установить не через `text.GotFocus += text_GotFocus`, а через тот же `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler`. Разницы в данном случае не будет. Вот мы и приходим к такому коду:

```
...
text = new TextBox();
text.Text = "Sample text";
...    
...
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), 
                                  UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
                                  new MouseButtonEventHandler(StopTextBoxClick), 
                                  true);
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), 
                                  UIElement.GotFocusEvent, 
                                  new RoutedEventHandler(text_GotFocus), 
                                  true);
...
...
private void text_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = sender as TextBox;
    if(text != null) text.SelectAll();
}

private void StopTextBoxClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = sender as TextBox;
    if (text != null && !text.IsKeyboardFocusWithin) 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
        text.Focus(); 
    } 
}
...
```

И все из-за того, что событие клика так работает - само устанавливает фокус и потом устанавливает каретку, снимая наши попытки выделения.

P.S. Опять же, событие действует на все элементы TextBox, поэтому если вам этого не надо, нужно в коде как-то ограничить события. Для этого внутри проверки `if (text != null && !text.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)` можно уже проверять дополнительные условия и свойства.

Comment: Ого, вот это подробный ответ!

Comment: @VladD, да просто попытка вольного перевода статьи из комментария.

Comment: Тем не менее, ответ очень хороший.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за добрые слова)

Answer (score 1):

Более простой вариант:

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address}" 
     GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
     SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged">
</TextBox>
```

C#

```
private bool isFocused = false;
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isFocused = true;
}

private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isFocused) {
        isFocused = false;
        (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в первоначальном варианте `selectall()` исправить на `select()`, то все работает без костылей.